# 'If' Statement Failing Check Involving String Array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to create a program in Java which allows the user to pick from a list of coffees contained in a String array and continues on, but it fails the check and prints out the else statement.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] flavors = {"Black", "French Vanilla", "Hazelnut", "Mango", "Cherokee", "anarcho-syndicalism", "Otis" };
```

...

```
System.out.println("Today we have " + Arrays.toString(flavors));
System.out.println("Please enter the name of the coffee you would like exactly as shown above: ");
String coffee = scan.next();
```

...

```
for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
    if (coffee == flavors[i]) {
        String selection = flavors[i];
```

Though not shown here, I believe everything's properly formatted later on in the program. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when comparing objects for equality in java, use `.equals()`. Use `==` for comparing primitives. In java, `String`s are objects.

change:

```
if (coffee == flavors[i]) {
```

to:

```
if (coffee.equals(flavors[i])) {
```

When comparing objects with `==`, they will only be equal if they are in fact the same instance.

Comment: That seems to have got it. Thanks, Asaph!